# app crashing due to deallocated instance

Tags: ios

I am having two screens one is for login:
The class name is LoginViewController. The screenshot is[image]

It consists of two textfields, Username and the password.

On clicking on forgot password:  this screen opens the class for this screen is ForgotPasswordViewController
[image]

On tapping the DOB textfield a date picker picker appears from which a date is selected. Now If I press the back button the login screen appears. everything is fine till now. Now if I Tap on The user or the password textfield then the app crashes will this log

2013-11-13 13:55:53.582 mRx[4684:60b] *** -[ForgotPasswordViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x15d7b510

I don't know what is causing this crash. please suggest something to deal with it. I have been 2 days on it but still not near to find the solution for this. Please comment if you need any other info regarding this.

the screenshot for the error trail is this:[image]

Please help

the code for the textfield to bring the date picker is this:

```
       #pragma mark - TextField Delegate Methods
```

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    self.txt_currentFocussedTextField = textField;
    [[AppDelegate sharedInstance] addToolbarForKeyboard:textField];

```
if (textField == self.txt_DOB) {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    _actionSheetPicker = [[ActionSheetDatePicker alloc] initWithTitle:@"" datePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate selectedDate:self.selectedDate minimumDate:Nil maximumDate:Nil target:self action:@selector(dateWasSelected:element:) origin:textField];
    self.actionSheetPicker.hideCancel = NO;
    [self.actionSheetPicker showActionSheetPicker];

}
```

}

The code in the .h file is this:

```
      #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "AbstractActionSheetPicker.h"

   @interface ForgotPasswordViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>

     @property (strong,nonatomic) UITextField * txt_currentFocussedTextField;
     @property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txt_username;
     //@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txt_lastname;
     @property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txt_DOB;
     @property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txt_phone;
     @property (strong,nonatomic)  IBOutlet UITextField * txt_zip;
     @property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField * txt_newPassword;


     @property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btn_save;

      @property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView * scrollview;

      @property (nonatomic, strong) AbstractActionSheetPicker *actionSheetPicker;
      @property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *selectedDate;

    - (void)forgotPasswordRequest;

      @end
```

Comment: Post some code of your .h file. A property should be retained but it isn't, but it is difficult to guess without the code. I assume that you are using ARC in your project.

Comment: but code regarding what, nothing is being called here it just the next screen loading through a segue and then returning to the login screen on the click of the back button. Then tapping on the textfield is causing the app to crash. The code for the back button is this. i have made it global for my whole app. also the code for the DOB textfiled when the date picker appears is this:

Comment: Is the UITextField declared as strong property?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that your `ForgotPasswordViewController` is observing an NSNotification, maybe `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and you didn't remove it as observer from the `NSNotificationCenter` when popped out from the navigation stack.
The problem is that the notification center tries to notify your already deallocated view controller.
 Use `- (void)removeObserver:(id)observer name:(NSString *)aName object:(id)anObject` in `viewDidDisappear:` or in `dealloc`.

Comment: thanks but what should be the name for observer and name and object. I mean what i should pass in these parameters

Comment: and also how to call this method. Can u please show it. it will be very helpful of you

Comment: Did you add your view controller as observer, using `- (void)addObserver:(id)observer selector:(SEL)aSelector name:(NSString *)aName object:(id)anObject`? If yes, then the parameters passed in that call. If not, then not this is your problem.

Comment: No I haven't added my view controller as an Observer in my code

Comment: but I think that the problem is due to the NSNotification only. can u suggest something to solve this now

Comment: You may try adding `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self]` to the ForgotPasswordViewController's dealloc, to check if that is the problem. If it is then you have to dig deeper to find where and how your view controller is registered as observer.

Comment: Hm, I think that this is a wrong direction, I could not guess based on the code posted, but if you are not using ARC then your ActionSheetDatePicker is leaking and perhaps it is who is calling back to your view controller. Maybe it is leaking even with ARC, so you should try dismissing it on viewWillDisappear.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41088/discussion-between-shikhar-and-imihaly)